# Make sure data does not get cleaned up in a static class

Tags: c#, static-methods, static-members

Is there a way to have a static class have static data that does not clear itself at the end of the function call?
i.e. given:

```
static class Class1
{
    static int[] _array;
    static Class1()
    {
         _array = new[] {2};
    }
    public static void FillArray()
    {
        List<int> temp = new List<int>();
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            temp.Add(i);
        _array = temp.ToArray();
    }
    public static int[] GetArray()
    {
        return _array;
    }
}
```

How can I get GetArray() to return something other than null?

**EDIT:** I want to call this code:

```
        int[] array1 = Class1.GetArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length;i++ )
            Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
        Class1.FillArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
```

and not get two 2s. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        int[] array1 = Class1.GetArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length;i++ )
            Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
        Class1.FillArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
```

In this code, you are getting the memory address of the first int[] {2} array and storing that as array1. Then when you call FillArray() you are creating the new List of arrays, and only setting its memory back to the _array in the class, not array1. That is not a reference to the memory in the class, but to the actual original array. So then, when you loop back through, you are still looking at the same memory block.

You should probably be doing this instead:

```
    int[] array1 = Class1.GetArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length;i++ )
        Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
    Class1.FillArray();
    array1 = Class1.GetArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
```

**Update** 
if you change your Class1 to look like this, you will see that you are changing the data in the class.

```
   static class Class1
   {
      static int[] _array;
      static Class1()
      {
         _array = new[] { 2 };
      }

      public static void FillArray()
      {
         List<int> temp = new List<int>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         {
            temp.Add(i);

         }
         _array = temp.ToArray();
         PrintArray();
      }

      public static int[] GetArray()
      {
         PrintArray();
         return _array;
      }

      private static void PrintArray()
      {
         foreach (int i in _array)
         {
            System.Console.Write(String.Format("{0},", i));
         }
      }

   }
```

Because it will print out the elements in the array after each call.

Comment: But I want the data in the static class to be modified... I know I can change the data in my current class.

Comment: You are modifying the data in the class. Class1._array is getting changed after the FillArray function. But why your code is printing out 2 twice is because you are looping through array1 not Class1._array.

Answer (score 1):

use a static constructor...

```
static class Class1
{
    private static readonly  int[] _array;
    static Class1()
    {
        List<int> temp = new List<int>();
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            temp.Add(i);
        _array = temp.ToArray();
    }

    public static int[] GetArray()
    {
        return _array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets say I want to change the data there, but have all my changes be "saved" something like fill it with the first hundred numbers, then replace that will the first 200 numbers. How can I do that?

Comment: @soandos: just remove `readonly`, then you can modify `_array` where you want.

Comment: But won't it get cleaned up then?

Comment: @soandos: What do you mean by "cleaned up"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If it is not read-only, then when I call GetArray, it will have been reset to null... or so I thought.

Comment: Not the returning part, the non-readonly part. Why won't the data get GC'ed just as if there is no static constructor?

Answer (score 0):

you can write something like

```
private static readonly int[] array = FillArray();
```

Comment: so remove the readonly keyword, you will be able to modify it when you want, and its hoing to be cleaned up when your static clqss will be destroyed, hence when your application will be closed

Comment: Not the case... It is a static class in another project. It seems to get cleaned up between every time I access it...